# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.4:start

Tags: maven, plugins, build

I'm trying to install maven with "mvn install" command and I'm getting this error message:

[WARNING] [beddedLocalContainer] org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Server did not start after 120000 milliseconds

[ERROR] Starting container [org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.Jetty9xEmbeddedLocalContainer@1ce2029b] failed, now stopping container

[INFO] [beddedLocalContainer] Jetty 9.4.6.v20170531 Embedded is stopping...

2018-05-17 23:55:27.062:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Thread-14: Stopped ServerConnector@3fb272f3{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}

2018-05-17 23:55:27.062:INFO:oejs.session:Thread-14: Stopped scavenging

2018-05-17 23:55:27.157:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Thread-14: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1a7468a0{/challenge-gui,null,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Chalenge\challenge-auttest\gui\target\challenge-gui-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war}

[image]

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: copy text into the question and not images...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours. I checked variety of versions of this plug-in, no one works. that error occurred because glassfish server has not started already.
I had to start glassfish server, before deploying (the command $ mvn install)
note that glassfish v4 needs JDK6 or JDK7. and glassfish v5 needs JDK7 or JDK8, not beyond.